# spring data jpa @query and pageable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA, and when I use `@Query` to to define a query ***WITHOUT*** `Pageable`, it works:

```
public interface UrnMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<UrnMapping, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from internal_uddi where urn like %?1% or contact like %?1%", 
           nativeQuery = true)
    List<UrnMapping> fullTextSearch(String text);
}
```

But if I add the second param `Pageable`, the `@Query` will NOT work, and Spring will parse the method's name, then throw the **exception** `No property full found`. Is this a bug?

```
public interface UrnMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<UrnMapping, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from internal_uddi where urn like %?1% or contact like %?1%",
           nativeQuery = true)
    Page<UrnMapping> fullTextSearch(String text, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A similar question was [asked on the Spring forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/126415-is-it-possible-to-use-query-and-pageable?p=611398#post611398), where it was pointed out that to apply pagination, a second subquery must be derived. Because the subquery is referring to the same fields, you need to ensure that your query uses aliases for the entities/tables it refers to. This means that where you wrote:

```sql
select * from internal_uddi where urn like
```

You should instead have:

```sql
select * from internal_uddi iu where iu.urn like ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with native query. Do you know if it is possible to achieve with native query?

Comment: If you want to write native queries, then you obviously need to write the query to do pagination yourself.

Answer (score 103):

You can use pagination with a native query. It is documented here: [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native)

"*You can however use native queries for pagination by specifying the count query yourself:
Example 59. Declare native count queries for pagination at the query method using @Query*"

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: `countQuery` also works for **non-native** queries, where Spring can not derive the number of elements from the original query.

Comment: Scroll down to [Example 64. Declare native count queries for pagination at the query method by using @Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) in the Spring Data JPA docs.

Comment: your solution works but i got illegalargumentexception even if the result is correct. Please can you check my question about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74494684/how-to-fetch-data-as-pageable-with-custom-query-in-jpa-without-illegalargumentex

Comment: If performance is critical, `countQuery` is not for you. It triggers an additional count query to achieve it. To avoid such an overhead cost, you can instead return a `Slice<T>` or a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 15):

Considering that the `UrnMapping` class is mapped to the `internal_uddi` table, I would suggest this:

```java
@Repository
public interface UrnMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<UrnMapping, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select iu from UrnMapping iu where iu.urn like %:text% or iu.contact like %:text%")
    Page<UrnMapping> fullTextSearch(@Param("text") String text, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Please note that you might have to turn off native queries with dynamic requests.

Answer (score 15):

With @Query , we can use pagination as well where you need to pass object of **Pageable** class at end of JPA method

For example:

```
Pageable pageableRequest = new PageRequest(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, rollNo);
```

*Where, 
page = index of page (index start from zero)

size = No. of records

Sort.Direction = Sorting as per rollNo

rollNo = Field in User class*

```
UserRepository repo
repo.findByFirstname("John", pageableRequest);

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE FIRSTNAME = :firstname)
  Page<User> findByLastname(@Param("firstname") String firstname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: He was asking for native query

Answer (score 6):

Please reference :[Spring Data JPA @Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query), if you are using Spring Data JPA version 2.0.4 and later. Sample like below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY id")
Page<User> findAllUsersWithPagination(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your query to:

```
select iu from internal_uddi iu where iu.urn....
```

description: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/126415-is-it-possible-to-use-query-and-pageable?p=611398#post611398

Answer (score 2):

I found it works different among different jpa versions, for debug, you'd better add this configurations to show generated sql, it will save your time a lot !

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

for spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE, it works good!

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "column_name");
int pageNumber = 3, pageSize = 5;
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber - 1, pageSize, sort);
```

```
@Query(value = "select * from integrity_score_view " +
        "where (?1 is null or data_hour >= ?1 ) " +
        "and (?2 is null or data_hour <= ?2 ) " +
        "and (?3 is null or ?3 = '' or park_no = ?3 ) " +
        "group by park_name, data_hour ",
        countQuery = "select count(*) from integrity_score_view " +
                "where (?1 is null or data_hour >= ?1 ) " +
                "and (?2 is null or data_hour <= ?2 ) " +
                "and (?3 is null or ?3 = '' or park_no = ?3 ) " +
                "group by park_name, data_hour",
        nativeQuery = true
)
Page<IntegrityScoreView> queryParkView(Date from, Date to, String parkNo, Pageable pageable);
```

you DO NOT write `order by` and `limit`, it generates the right sql

Answer (score 2):

Declare native count queries for pagination at the query method by using @Query

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
  countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
  nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Hope this helps

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - without `Pageable` method works fine.
When added as method parameter - doesn't work.

After playing with DB console and native query support came up to decision that method works like it should. However, only for ***upper case letters***.
Logic of my application was that all `names` of entity starts from ***upper case letters***.

Playing a little bit with it. And discover that `IgnoreCase` at method name do the "magic" and here is working solution:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository 
                            extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    Page<Employee> findAllByNameIgnoreCaseStartsWith(String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Where entity looks like:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblEmployees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "empID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "empName", length = 25)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "empActive")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_dpID")
    private Department department;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this but instead of an entity, I have a view. I want to query the view but do not want to write the native SQL because the `LIKE` parameter comes in unescaped (with %, ~*, etc0)

Answer (score 1):

When using nativeQuery that is having (nativeQuery = true), you may do the pagination yourself in the query by adding (LIMIT :sizeValue OFFSET :page)

Note:
Your page value passed to this method should be offset * size

Example

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person " +    
                   "LIMIT ?1 OFFSET ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<List<TDriverJob>> findPersons(int size, int page);
```

Comment: Avoid using `Optional<List<T>>`, just use `List<T>`. When it comes to lists (and collections in general), there is already a clear way to represent "no result", and that is an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

For me return type of Page  with Pageable was not working, but on changing the return type to List  or Optional<?> was working fine.

```
public interface UrnMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<UrnMapping, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from internal_uddi where urn like %?1% or contact like %?1%",
           nativeQuery = true)
    Page<UrnMapping> fullTextSearch(String text, Pageable pageable); // this doesnt work, for this you need to use countQuery

 List<UrnMapping> fullTextSearch(String text, Pageable pageable); // this is working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above solution and non worked , finally I removed the Sorting from Pagination and it worked

Answer (score 0):

the following tutorial helped me
-> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

At this point 4.3. Spring Data JPA Versions Prior to 2.0.4

VERY IMPORTANT to add `\ n-- #pageable \ n`
Without this I was wrong

Also the pagination setting must be without ordering

```
PageRequest paginaConf = new PageRequest ((param1 - 1)
                                                 , param2);
```

Finally to convert the Page <Object []>

```
  Page <Object []> list = myQueryofRepo ();
         List <XXXModel> lstReturn = myConversor (list.getContent ());
         Page <XXXModel> ret = new PageImpl <XXXModel> (lstReturn, pageConf, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me for a while but I managed with a very smooth solution.

The challenge is JPA did not automatically detect the count query so I resolved to use the `countName` which according JPA docs  `Returns the name of the javax.persistence.NamedQuery to be used to execute count queries when pagination is used. Will default to the named query name configured suffixed by .count.`

So I created a named query

```java
@NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "[queryName].count",
            query = [your count query],
            resultSetMapping = "[query resultSetMapping name]"
        )
    }
```

As indicated, the count query should be suffixed with `.count`

Count query returns `Long` so add the resultSetMapping as

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="[query resultSetMapping name]",
    columns={@ColumnResult(name="count", type = Long.class)})
```

Then in your repository, use the count query as indicated below

```java
@Query(countName ="[queryName].count" , nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object> [mainQuery](...params)
```

Hope this helps!