# How to get all results in one page using Spring Data Pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I want to get all the results in single page, I've tried with

```
Pageable p = new PageRequest(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
return customerRepository.findAll(p);
```

Above is not working, is there any methods to achieve this? Seems like it cannot be achieved from custom query as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345081/spring-data-jpa-query-and-pageable).

Comment: And why would you even use pagination in that case? Makes 0 sense.

Comment: Yeah you are correct..but I am trying to make an api..sometimes it just ask for the all data (with different search query)..but should be displayed in a table which is used also for paginated results in different time. So I want to keep the response format untouched.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your page request is incorrect because you are looking for results on the wrong page. It should be:

```
PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The first page for results is 0. Since you're returning all records, they are all on this page.

Comment: This answer is not perfect. You will get a max page size limitation of 1000 which means you will not get all results when your items is greater than 1000.

Comment: @MaxPeng That's highly dependent on data store type. And the question is pretty much data store agnostic.

Comment: @BranislavLazic Well, my point is spring data itself has a little trap which might override the the max page size you passed in, refer  to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java#L50

Comment: This is deprecated as of now. You need to use `PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: what's the easiest way to make the first page of results be 1 ?

Comment: @DonCode make a `Top1` or `First1` query for one result.

Comment: Solutions which have a caveat are not proper solutions, IMO. Using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a hack. The correct solution is to use `Pageable.unpaged()`.

Answer (score 141):

The more correct way is to use [Pageable.unpaged()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#unpaged--)

```
Pageable wholePage = Pageable.unpaged();
return customerRepository.findAll(wholePage);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks

Comment: But I still want to sort it, how do i do it?

Comment: @Legna you can send a Sort Parameter in the repository method . 

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-six-sorting/

.

org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

myRepository.findAll(sortByIdAsc());
 and pass 
new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");

Comment: @MohammedIdris, What I meant is that Pageable.unpaged() doesn't allow sorting. My question was strictly related to the suggestion of using Pageable.unpaged()

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762676/7589291)

Answer (score 10):

If you pass null for Pageable, Spring will ignore it and brings all data.

```
Pageable p = null;
return customerRepository.findAll(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of spirng-data-commons@2.1.0 correct syntax is `PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.
You can look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/6951d8b7116ac319cf086600f1803173e85c9cf0/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.java#L83)

Comment: `Pageable.unpaged()` is the correct solution.