# fetch all records using PagingAndSortingRepository in spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, rest, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I am making an application in which I have used `spring-data-jpa`. I have used `PagingAndSortingRepository` and its working fine. I can see all the records returned as pages.

I have one scenario where I need to retrieve all records for a single day. I need to fetch all records using single request. I found we can set Page size as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But I read maximum records that a Page can have is 1000. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053786/how-to-get-all-results-in-one-page-using-spring-data-pagination).

How should I configure the `Pageable` object to fetch all records in single request.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer (2019-02-26)**

The best solution is probably this one now:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924025/7709086

That is:

```java
var pagedEntities = repo.findAll(Pageable.unpaged());
```

**Old answer**

Do not pass it, aka `findAll()` instead of `findAll(Pageable pageable)`.

If returning a `Page` (and not a `List`) is mandatory, you can wrap it afterwards:

```java
var pagedEntities = new PageImpl(repo.findAll());
```