# How to create unpaged but sorted Pageable.of(unpaged, unpaged, Sort ) to spring data jpa repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, pageable

How do I pass a `Pageable` object to Spring JPA Repository with only Sorting information? 
I want something like this:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(null, null, Sort());
```

I know it takes `int` as `page` and `size` but if we can somehow not use those values and give an unpaged result with only

`Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "age")`

We could use a high number like `1000` , `1000` for page and size but I do not want to hardcode these values.

I am also not looking to create a custom impl for `Pageable`.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation for the current version of Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting), you can pass a `Sort` directly to a query method, so you could have two versions of the same query method:

- One receiving a `Pageable`, for use when you have a "full" `Pageable`.
- Another one receiving a `Sort`, for use when you just want to perform sorting.

Comment: This is a good option, having two methods in the repository class. 
However, what if I want to have only one method with `Pageable` as a parameter? Is it possible to achieve sorting using Pageable only?

Comment: @MohammedIdris well `Pageable` is an interface so you can always make your own implementation. I guess you can use `org.springframework.data.domain.Unpaged` as a guide and provide a similar implementation that stores the `Sort` and returns it via `getSort`. Anyway, you should consider why you want to pass a `Pageable` if you do not want to do paging.

Comment: I guess I could create an implementation, however, for passing `Pageable` but not using it, I already have a `Repository` method with `Pageable` which is being used by my `service class`. I thought of using the same method to get sorting without paging. If this is not possible I can create my own impl or I can add a method with `Sort` as a parameter.

Comment: Really you can't.  
As soon as a **Pageable** with **isPaged=false** is provided the information in the Pageable is not used by **SimpleJpaRepository** class.
The only way to go as an alternative if you want to use always a **Pageable** (so the **Sort** information is used) is to create a new one with **Integer.MAX_VALUE** as page size.

Comment: @rubensa as far as i know max pages count in Pageable smaller as at Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score -3):

You could pass `Pageable.unpaged()` in the query and then sort the result (`list.getContent().sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getName))`) if you are adamant about using the existing query.

Comment: this is unacceptable since sorting will be done in memory, not at db level

Comment: This is not so "unacceptable". As it is requested to go "unpaged" you will get the whole dataset in memory anyway. Sorting will add overhead but ,for dataset you know being manageable in memory, that option worth being mentioned ... with a warning.