# Execute two queries with JPA Criteria API with the same where clauses but different output types

Tags: java, criteria, jpa-criteria

I want to load `data` and `count(data)` via Criteria API. Just loading `data` and then checking the result list won't work, because I'm limiting my results with a `maxResults` parameter, while `count(data)` is supposed to check the amount of `data` without any limitations. I have a set of `Predicate` filters that gets applied to both queries, though.

Mabye I have a general misunderstanding here, but I can't reuse much of the query, since right at the creation, we have to type it to the wanted query result type:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<QueryResultObject> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(QueryResultObject.class);
```

Afterwards, we create a `Root` and `Join`s for this specific already typed query:

```
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Order> orderMeta = metamodel.entity(Order.class);
EntityType<Shop> shopMeta = metamodel.entity(Shop.class);

Root<Order> order = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Shop> shop = order.join(orderMeta.getSingularAttribute("shop", Shop.class));
Join<Shop, Address> address = shop.join(shopMeta.getSingularAttribute("address", Address.class));
```

Next, I'm selecting a bunch of stuff (that corresponds to the constructor of `QueryResultObject`):

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(order.get("id"), order.get("date"),
    address.get("country"), order.get("item").get("name"));
```

Now I'm constructing a list of `Predicate`s for filtering. My goal is to re-use the same list for the `count` query, since it's a potentially big, complex to build list. However, in those `Predicate`s, I'm using my `Root` and `Join`s that are already coupled to `criteriaQuery`, and therefore, to the target class `QueryResultObject`. Sometimes it works, sometimes I encounter problems, so maybe there's a better way to operate here.

```
List<Predicate> whereClauses = new ArrayList<>();
// ... fill it, e.g.:
Predicate filter = criteriaBuilder.equal(address.get("country"), "US");
whereClauses.add(filter);

criteriaQuery.where(whereClauses.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Now I'm ready to execute the query:

```
TypedQuery<QueryResultObject> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(first));
typedQuery.setMaxResults(maxResults);

var results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Jay, it worked! When looking into the generated query, `order` got assigned to `generatedAlias0`, `shop` to `generatedAlias2` and `address` to `generatedAlias1`. As you can see, it wasn't assigned in the order of the joins, but rather `shop` was skipped - maybe because nothing from `shop` was in the `multiselect`? I haven't really found much about that and I think it's the source of my problem.

Now, when creating a `count` query, I have to redo quite a bit:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaCountQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Order> orderCount = criteriaCountQuery.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Shop> shopCount = orderCount.join(orderMeta.getSingularAttribute("shop", Shop.class));
Join<Shop, Address> addressCount = shopCount.join(shopMeta.getSingularAttribute("address", Address.class));
```

And finally, I'm trying to reuse my filters and fetch a single number:

```
criteriaCountQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(orderCount));
criteriaCountQuery.where(whereClauses.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaCountQuery).getSingleResult();
```

However, that's where I encounter a problem: I get a `QueryException: could not resolve property` error that says that `Shop` has no field `country`. Examining the query shows that this time, the aliases were generated in order (probably because of the different `select` clause), and therefore the `Predicate`s don't quite match anymore.

I don't think that this use case is that exotic, so there's probably some easier and cleaner way to do it? Happy to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Throw out the `maxResults`, then count the data that's returned and afterwards trim your list to the desired size?

Comment: I don't know if this is efficient. I'm loading data for a frontend table from a potentionally big dataset and I only need the data for one table page, therefore the limit. Loading the whole thing would remove any lazy loading advantage.

Comment: Depending on your mapping, it seems that hibernate might ignore `setMaxResults` anyways. [Read answers here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-jpql-or-hql). That said, I always found criteria queries to be cumbersome. I would suggest going to JPQL queries with `Pageable`s. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345081/spring-data-jpa-query-and-pageable). Here JPA will generate the count query as long as it is not a native query